# Using Lodash, how can I transform this data to the desired format?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm fairly new to lodash and suspect that it can help me transform my data in the way I want. I've been reading the [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs#union) but to be honest it's not sinking in, I'm not seeing the correct combination of operations I need.

Here is what I want to do:

```
var configs = [ { 
      configId: 1,
      options: [ {categoryId: 1, id: 100},
                 {categoryId: 2, id: 200},
                 {categoryId: 3, id: 300} ] },
    { 
      configId: 2,
      options: [ {categoryId: 1, id: 105},
                 {categoryId: 2, id: 210} ] },
    { 
      configId: 3,
      options: [ {categoryId: 2, id: 200},
                 {categoryId: 1, id: 165},
                 {categoryId: 3, id: 300} ] }
];

//  I want the above to look like this:
/*
[ {categoryId: 1, ids: [100, 105, 165]},
  {categoryId: 2, ids: [200, 210]},
  {categoryId: 3, ids: [300]} ]
*/
```

And here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sklett/6rpqmf41/) if you want to experiment.

When I look at the problem I think I want to:

1. Combine all the `configs` objects so I have one big array of `options` objects
2. Group by `categoryId`
3. And then I really lose my way... I suspect I could use reduce() here, but then I also think I need a map() to actually produce the transformed object.

Anyway, I'm looping on this and not making progress, I'm hoping someone can point me the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ES2015 Syntax:

```
_.map(
  _.groupBy(_.flatMap(configs, config => config.options), 'categoryId'), 
  (val, key) => ({categoryId: key, ids: _.uniq(_.map(val, v => v.id)) })
)
```

ES5 compatible (generated by Babel):

```
_.map(
  _.groupBy(
    _.flatMap(configs, function (config) {
    return config.options;
    }), 
  'categoryId'), 
  function (val, key) {
    return {
        categoryId: key,
        ids: _.uniq(_.map(val, function (v) {
            return v.id;
        }))
    };
});
```

Explanation:

```
_.flatMap(configs, config => config.options)
```

Takes `options` array from each configs object, flattens them into a single array of `[{categoryId: xx, id: yy}, ...]`

```
[ {categoryId:1,id:100},
  {categoryId:2,id:200},
  {categoryId:3,id:300},
  {categoryId:1,id:105},
  {categoryId:2,id:210},
  {categoryId:2,id:200},
  {categoryId:1,id:165},
  {categoryId:3,id:300} ]


_.groupBy(..., 'categoryId')
```

Groups above array by their `categoryId`, as `[{xx: [categoryId: xx, id: yy}, ...]`

```
{
    1:[
        {categoryId:1,id:100},
        {categoryId:1,id:105},
        {categoryId:1,id:165} ],
    2:[
        {categoryId:2,id:210},
        {categoryId:2,id:200},
        {categoryId:2,id:200} ],
    3:[
        {categoryId:3,id:300},
        {categoryId:3,id:300} ] }

_.map(..., (val, key) => ({categoryId: key, ids: _.uniq(_.map(val, v => v.id)) }))
```

Receives `val = [{xx: [categoryId: xx, id: yy}, ...]`, `key: xx` and maps them to object where `categoryId` is set to received key, and `ids` to array of unique `id`s from grouped objects. Result is the array you wanted.

```
[ {
    categoryId:1,
    ids:[100,105,165]},
  {
    categoryId:2,
    ids:[200,210]},
  {
    categoryId:3,
    ids:[300]}]
```

Comment: Excellent and I really appreciate the explanation portion of your answer, thank you. I edited and added the output of each stage as that's how my brain thinks (is limited?), maybe others will find it helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @SteveK, it's probably more useful to see actual data than my "template data".

Answer (score 1):

```js
var configs = [{
  configId: 1,
  options: [
    {categoryId: 1, id: 100},
    {categoryId: 2, id: 200},
    {categoryId: 3, id: 300} 
  ]
}, { 
  configId: 2,
  options: [
    {categoryId: 1, id: 105},
    {categoryId: 2, id: 210}
  ]
}, { 
  configId: 3,
  options: [
    {categoryId: 2, id: 200},
    {categoryId: 1, id: 165},
    {categoryId: 3, id: 300}
  ]
}];

var result = _.chain(configs)
  .flatMap(config => config.options)
  .groupBy(id => id.categoryId)
  .map((list, categoryId) => ({
    categoryId: +categoryId,
    ids: _.chain(list)
      .map(x => x.id)
      .uniq()
      .value()
  }))
  .value();

document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(result,null,2);
```

```css
body {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although both answers are showing the same technique I picked the other one because I liked the explanation section.